# Searching Queries Programmatically

Tags: algorithm, search

I am doing a research project and for that purpose I need to get results for nearly 1.5 million query.

Can any one suggest how can I achieve it? If it helps I need the results only from a specific site.

I saw all search engines provide API but I don't think anyone has free limit which could handle million queries.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl the web site and use your own search engine to query it. You can use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) for example as an open source library that provides the "search engine" functionality. You will need to create a document for each page, and feed it to an IndexWriter, and later on, query your index.

An alternative is use the [paid](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/72334?hl=en) API provided by search engines, that allows much higher number of queries.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to crawl the website?

Comment: @Coder Hacker how about running dfs/bfs on links elements (parsed html) which point to the same website ;>

Comment: @fex I figured I had to do this! I was hoping someone somewhere keeps all pages publicly indexed

Comment: @coderhacker I highly doubt you will find free service like that. btw. if you gonna crawl it by hand - check sitemap - that might help you